# Get the values of a dictionary as list of values

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value, data-manipulation

I'm trying to obtain the values that are stored inside a dict but I couldn't do it.

```
dict = {"user": {"tw_id": [["1080231111188251398"], ["1080111112808902656"], [], ["1080081111173306369"], [], ["1080491111114200192"]]}}
```

I tried `list(map(...)` but I got a list of the characters as a result.

Please help!

I want to get a list like this:

```
list = ["1080231111188251398","1080111112808902656","1080081111173306369","1080491111114200192"]
```

Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists for how to flatten the list of lists. Do that for each dictionary element,  and concatenate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/4518341) For example:

```
# Using simpler data for readability
d = {"user": {"tw_id": [["a"], ["b"], [], ["c"], [], ["d"]]}}

from itertools import chain
L = list(chain.from_iterable(d['user']['tw_id']))
print(L)  # -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

BTW don't use variable names like `dict` and `list` since they shadow the builtin types `dict` and `list`.

Comment: Thank you!! It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension to flatten, which accesses the first item of each subarray (assuming each subarray will only ever contain 1 item):

```
lst = [i[0] for i in dct["user"]["tw_id"] if i]
```

---

```
>>> dct = {"user": {"tw_id": [["1080231111188251398"], ["1080111112808902656"], [], ["1080081111173306369"], [], ["1080491111114200192"]]}}
>>> lst = [i[0] for i in dct["user"]["tw_id"] if i]
>>> lst
['1080231111188251398', '1080111112808902656', '1080081111173306369', '1080491111114200192']
>>>
```

Also, never use `dict` or `list` for variable names, it shadows the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, let me know if is the case.

you have a dict of dicts, so first of all you need to get the first level (`users`) then you will have a a dict where the value is a list.

```
> some = {"user": {"tw_id": [["1080231111188251398"], ["1080111112808902656"], [], ["1080081111173306369"], [], ["1080491111114200192"]]}}                                           
> some["user"]    
{'tw_id': [['1080231111188251398'], ['1080111112808902656'], [], ['1080081111173306369'], [], ['1080491111114200192']]}
> some["user"]["tw_id"]
[['1080231111188251398'], ['1080111112808902656'], [], ['1080081111173306369'], [], ['1080491111114200192']]
```